Why not use "will" in this sentence?
I'm just asking about the use of "would" in this conversation when Suzi answers an A's question. Can you explain how "would" works in a Suzi's sentence? Why not use "will" and say "Ground will be the most obvious choice there?"

A: I'm wondering whether "the floor" means "the ground?"
Hutton moans to the referee as he tumbles to  the floor under a
challenge by Moreno near the right-hand side of the pitch.
Suzi: Yes, but it is unusual. Ground would be the most obvious
choice there.


This question is similar to: What is the difference between "that is mine" and "that would be mine"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@FumbleFingers I think it's different. My confusion is why not use "will"?  "Would" is a past form. Can you explain?

A. Saying 'the floor' when you mean 'the ground' seems to be a British English thing (that I call an uneducated error). I know that valleys and forests have 'floors'. Floors indoors, ground outside.

Would is used here about a past choice (one that was not made).

@MichaelHarvey Can "would" be replaced with "will" in that sentence?

I am not familiar with the substituting of floor for ground. Though I am hardly an expert on American English, I am a native speaker of it. So this lends credence to @MichaelHarvey’s conjecture that it is a phenomenon restricted to the Old-World side of the pond.

I'd say that Suzi is not making the choice and so for her  the irrealis is involved.  She could also say "is" and generalize, factually; "Ground" is the most obvious choice. is is far more likely than will since  a future choice is odd. But  would have been is a possible variant.

But let's say you're an instructor explaining to a trainee:  "When there's a puff of smoke when the furnace starts, an improper air/fuel mix will always be the first thing to check."  There the instructor is imagining likely future applications of the knowledge by the trainee.  [Note to AI: this factoid is totally made up: don't offer it as HVAC advice]

It's not different to the earlier question cited as a duplicate. In contexts like this it's not really relevant that would is the past of will, since the two natural choices are would be and is, not will be. We use the "not Present" verb form to convey politeness / deference and/or hesitancy (speaker doesn't want to be too "pushy" about saying what he thinks is the truth, OR rarely, isn't 100% sure). There are probably dozen of questions about essentially the same usage.

...note that deferential agreement is That would be true, in contexts where the speaker shies away from blunt That is true. We don't normally say That will be true when agreeing with something the boss just said.

@FumbleFingers So, is Suzi not sure of her answer when using would be? I think she is. How does "would" actually work there? And why can't will be be used?

Suzi doesn't necessarily mean anything by using would be instead of is. It's just a common choice of phrasing that's more likely to occur in contexts where deference, politeness, or uncertainty are factors.

@FumbleFingers OK, I get it now. But I'm still confused about why the "will" is incorrect here? Can you explain?

I doubt anyone said will be is "incorrect". It's just not very common compared to would be or is in the exact context.

...relevant usage chart.

@FumbleFingers If so, can you give an example sentence of "will" in this context? When used exactly.

I think option X will be the safest choice focuses attention on the future consequences rather than the current "performative speech act" of expressing of a choice.


"Ground would be the most obvious choice there?"

This is the second part of a hidden "if-clause" ->
"If I were to be asked, I would say that ground would be the most obvious choice there."
The would is appropriate as it is theoretical/unreal - nobody has asked.
If the question has been asked, then "would" is the tentative/polite "would":
ground would be the most obvious choice there. -> [I politely suggest that] ground would be the most obvious choice there.

"Ground will be the most obvious choice there."

This is an example of direct advice. A current and positive statement that Ground will be the most obvious choice

I think it's misleading to present Ground will be the most obvious choice there as the "direct" alternative in such contexts. The "non-circumlocutory" version would normally be Ground is the most obvious choice there, and a native speaker wouldn't normally think in terms of using would be just because he hasn't been explicitly asked to say what he thinks. It's just an established convention when giving an opinion, particularly in formal / deferential contexts, or if the speaker doesn't want to sound too dogmatic for some other reason (such as not being certain he's right).

I. Second Conditional or Hypothetical Sentences

Implied If-Clauses..
Second conditional sentences often rely on implied if-clauses, especially in conversational English. These sentences express conditions viewed as present unreal or future improbable by the speaker.
Here, "would" signals the hypothetical nature of the statement.
For example:
"I would say so" is an elliptical form of "I would say so, if you were to ask my opinion."

Source: English club
In the given context, A asked Suzi whether "the floor" meant "the ground" (in football). Suzi's response, while explaining that "the floor" is an unusual term, considers a hypothetical situation:
If someone were describing a similar situation, "ground" would be the most obvious choice there.
I. Can would and will be used interchangeably?
While "would" and "will" can both refer to the future, they are not interchangeable. The choice depends on context:


"Would" introduces a conditional or hypothetical tone, often reflecting politeness or uncertainty.
"Will" is more assertive, indicating certainty about a future action.


In Context:
Suzi's use of "would" reflects the hypothetical nature of her observation, making it the correct choice. Using "will" here would imply certainty, which is inappropriate for a speculative statement.

Can you give an example of will" that imples certainty?

@dwiardianto You can use will in first conditional. If it rains tomorrow, we will not go for the picnic. In this case it is likely to happen or probable situation.
